# How to find out the wireless authentication mode?

Tags: api, dbus

I'm trying to get the authentication mode (WPA/WEP) on all the available AccessPoints via DBUS  API(in Linux). [NetworkManager API](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/spec-08.html#org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint) describes a property WPAFLAGS but I don't get anything out of it (I get Null Flag everytime). [D-Feet DBUS debugger](https://fedorahosted.org/d-feet/) also doesn't show anything. Am I missing something, or is the API broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are doing something wrong:

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/995 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint' string:'WpaFlags'
method return sender=:1.1188 -> dest=:1.2189 reply_serial=2
   variant       uint32 324
$ dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/994 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint' string:'WpaFlags'
method return sender=:1.1188 -> dest=:1.2190 reply_serial=2
   variant       uint32 332
$ dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/991 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint' string:'WpaFlags'
method return sender=:1.1188 -> dest=:1.2191 reply_serial=2
   variant       uint32 276
```

Answer (score 1):

What you posted returns:

> dbus-send: Data item "method" is badly formed

I believe question was about:

```
interface.Get("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint", "WpaFlags")
```

and it always returns 0